# Creating a second version of my app trouble changing package name

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-package-managers

I am trying to create a second version of my app. I took the folder it was created in by Android Studio. I successfully changed the package name in the manifest and changed every instance by using ctr-shift-f.

My problem now is that when I build the app and try and run it on my phone I get this error:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: htc-htc_one-HT359W907227
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliofreev3/BeerPprtfolio/build/apk/BeerPprtfolio-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
Installing com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
Success


Launching application: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.beerportfolio.freeBP.MainDrawer2.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.beerportfolio.freeBP.MainDrawer2" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.beerportfolio.freeBP.MainDrawer2 }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.beerportfolio.freeBP.MainDrawer2} does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in Manifest xml you did not change the Activity packages correctly?

The device shell cannot find Activity:

> com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.beerportfolio.freeBP.MainDrawer2

so check where it is linked in the manifest and check if everything is correct with it.

Comment: this isn't an answer, so should be posted as a comment on the OP instead.

Comment: here is my manifest, I dont see anything:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1be383934b0ced0838ca

Comment: In the manifest you posted, there is no package: "com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro", but there is "com.beerportfolio.freeBP".

Comment: yea thats what I am trying to make it

Comment: But on log you posted, there in a part: "Installing com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro", so pm install doesn't use the manifest that you have posted, but uses some other manifest.